# How to get a WPF command to execute on row double click of the Infragistics WPF datagrid?

Tags: xamdatagrid

I have a WPF XamDataGrid (I'm using the MVVM pattern, xaml below) and I need it to show the record details in another window when the user double clicks on a row. I have the command which gets the job done, but I don't know how to fire it up as I do with buttons. I want to be able to execute the command when the user double clicks a row, so I need to send the double clicked row (or its ID) as a parameter to the comand. Is it possible?

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding SomeList}">
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False"/>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                <igDP:FieldLayout >
                    <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                        <igDP:Field  Name="ObjectId" Label="Id" Width="Auto"/>
                        <igDP:Field  Name="Description" Label="Object Description" Width="Auto"/>
                    </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                </igDP:FieldLayout>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 6):

I use MVVM pattern too and write such as:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Path=StaffList, Mode=OneWay}>
  ...
  <igDP:XamDataGrid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" 
                  Command="{Binding Path=EditStaffCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataItem}"/>
  </igDP:XamDataGrid.InputBindings>
  ...
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

Where `EditStaffCommand` and `StaffList` - properties from view model

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Attached command behaviours (http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/). They allow to bind commands to events.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a behavior to add a binding between your ViewModel’s Command and the Double Click event of the Grid.

See the following post for more information:

http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/67749/343013.aspx#343013